# Grouping results in ui-bootstrap typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm trying to figure out how to group results in the dropdown of UI-Bootstrap's typeahead:[image]

Is there in easy way to support it?

Comment: Nope, this is not supported in the current version (0.10.0).

Comment: I know your question is older, but there's a great answer here in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116635/angularui-bootstrap-typeahead-grouping-results. I did use a similar approach with angular-strap.