# AngularUI-Bootstrap Typeahead: Grouping results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I am implementing typeahead using AngularUI-Bootstrap. I need to show the results grouped based on some values coming from the database. Here's a sample scenario

1. There are some users in the database, each user has a "Department". One user name can be available in multiple departments.
2. The end-user types in the names to search users from the database and retrieves the list in the typeahead list. Since one user name can belong to multiple departments, the requirement is to show the user names grouped by different departments. Something like this:
   [image]
3. Then the user can select the desired user name and proceed.

As per the `Typeahead` documentation present [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), I don't see any option to cater to my requirement.

I have tried the this workaround: Whenever the typeahead array is getting formed, I appended the user department to the array element:

```
$scope.fetchUsers = function(val) {
        console.log("Entered fetchUsers function");
        return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/TestWeb/users", {
            params : {
                username : val
            }
        }).then(function(res) {
            console.log("Response:",res);
            var users = [];
            angular.forEach(res.data, function(item) {
                users.push(item.UserName + " - " + item.UserDepartment);
            });
            console.log("users=",users);
            return users;
        });
    };
```

This way, at least the end user sees the department. But when I select the record, the selected value is the full content of the array element. Below is sample screenshot to elaborate:

**HTML**

Users from local service

```
<pre>Model: {{userList | json}}</pre>
<input type="text" ng-model="userList" placeholder="Users loaded from local database" 
typeahead="username for username in fetchUsers($viewValue)" 
typeahead-loading="loadingUsers" class="form-control">
<i ng-show="loadingUsers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
```

**User types in the string**

[image: Search result]

**User selects one record**

[image: user selects one record]

I want to avoid the department (in this case, string `- Desc 4` ) when user selects a record.

Is there any way I can achieve this grouping without any workaround? Or is there any way I can enhance my workaround?

Comment: Did you find any solution of this. showing results in Typeahead grouped by a category.   I'm also trying to do same. Can you please suggest any pointers for solution ?

Comment: The solution I used is the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for replying

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I used to have a similar requirement and here is how I did it that time.

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/zujdouvB4bz7tFX8HaNu?p=preview

The trick is to set the `typeahead-template-url` to a custom item template:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Users loaded from local database"
    ng-model="selectedUser"
    typeahead="user as user.name for user in getUsers($viewValue)"
    typeahead-template-url="typeahead-item.html" />
```

The item template, this represent each item in a dropdown:

```
<div class="typeahead-group-header" ng-if="match.model.firstInGroup">Desc {{match.model.group}}</div>
<a>
  <span ng-bind-html="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
</a>
```

As you can see, there is an `ng-if` to show a group header if that item has a property `firstInGroup` set to true.

The `firstInGroup` properties are populated like this using lodashjs:

```
$scope.getUsers = function (search) {
  var filtered = filterFilter(users, search);

  var results = _(filtered)
    .groupBy('group')
    .map(function (g) {
      g[0].firstInGroup = true; // the first item in each group
      return g;
    })
    .flatten()
    .value();

  return results;
}
```

Hope this fit to your requirement too.

Comment: Hey @runTarm, i don't understand the working of 
var filtered = filterFilter(users, search);
var results = _(filtered)  .
What is the working of this and how to use this, Please help me.

Comment: I am getting this issue in console after adding the `underscore` library.
`TypeError: _(...).groupBy(...).map is not a function`, please give some explanation about `_(filtered)` things.

Comment: great solution! There is a small bug - we need to copy `users` list before filtering: `var filtered = filterFilter(angular.copy(users), search);`
http://plnkr.co/edit/gdxBToatIHMFbH7e6QzA?p=preview

Comment: any solution for this problem `TypeError: _(...).groupBy(...).map is not a function Parser.functionCall (angular.js:6)
    at OPERATORS.| (angular.js:5)
    at Object.Parser.binaryFn.extend.constant [as source] (angular.js:5)
    at link.getMatchesAsync (ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:3)`

Please help me to out of it. its happening while switching the tabs in my website, but works fine after page load.

Comment: I had the same problems. I managed to fix                 
`var results = _.groupBy(myArray, 'group');

                results = _.map(results, function(g) {
                    g[0].firstInGroup = true; // the first item in each group
                    return g;
                });

                results = _.flatten(results);
                return results;`

I don't need .value, and if you need it, just add `results = _.values(results);`at the end, before returning

Comment: Regarding the questions above: `underscore != lodash`. If you use `underscore`, you should call `_.chain(filtered)` to start the chain. Note that this is not entirely equivalent to `_(filtered)`, since the latter is lazy. In this case we use all values anyway, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/DmoEWzAUHGEXuHILLPBp?p=preview

instead of creating new objects here:

```
 angular.forEach(res.data, function(item) {
                users.push(item.UserName + " - " + item.UserDepartment);
            });
```

use create template :

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
    <a> {{ match.model.name}} - department : {{match.model.dept}}</a>
  </script>
```

and use it in your **Typeahead** directive

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected"
 typeahead="user.name as user for user in users | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control"
typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html">
```

Comment: It's a really nice solution. Upvoted :), but haven't accepted the answer since I am looking for actual grouping.

Comment: @PramodKarandikar  , Did you find what you were searching for ?  Grouping results in typeahead . If you could share your solution here that would be great.