# Displaying multiple grouped data sets using Angular UI Bootstrap typeahead?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm building a search feature that needs to use a typeahead that will suggest results from multiple datasets of different type of items.

I have used the [Angular UI Bootstrap's typeahead directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) for a single data. The documentation mention custom templates, but nothing about supporting grouping of results.

For example, I would like to be able to type in "san" and see results for people and cities, with group labels:

Cities

- San Francisco
- San Diego

People

- Santana
- Sanchez
- Sandip

Is this possible using Angular UI Bootstrap's typeahead?

Answer (score 1):

Found this discussion very helpful to set me on the right track:

[AngularUI Bootstrap Typeahead Grouping Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116635/angularui-bootstrap-typeahead-grouping-results)

The overall approach is to:

1. add a "data type" identifier to each set of results
2. merge data sets together
3. during filtering, identify the first item of each data type.
4. a custom typeahead template, look for the "first" identifier, and include additional HTML to label the section of results